# Installing a program PHOEBE 2

Tags: installation

Here are the instructions: [Download & Install PHOEBE 2.1.6](http://phoebe-project.org/install)

1. First attempt:

   ```
   pip install numpy phoebe

   Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.11.0) Collecting phoebe Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/18/65d72fe5cf21c9e678d81408566a535026c782327869b7dcbffecd347de5/phoebe-2.1.6.tar.gz Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in File "/tmp/pip-install-ty7hrmts/phoebe/setup.py", line 6 print "Numpy is needed for running and building of PHOEBE" ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

   ----------------------------------------

   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ty7hrmts/phoebe/ You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
   ```
2. Second attempt from https://github.com/phoebe-project/phoebe2

   I have problem with

   ```
   python setup.py build


   python setup.py build /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires' warnings.warn(msg) running build running config_cc unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options running config_fc unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options running build_src build_src building extension "libphoebe" sources building extension "phoebe.algorithms.ceclipse" sources build_src: building npy-pkg config files running build_py running build_ext customize UnixCCompiler customize UnixCCompiler using build_check customize UnixCCompiler customize UnixCCompiler using build_check OS: Linux OS version: 4.10.0-38-generic sh: 1: c++: not found Compiler: c++ Compiler version: C compiler: i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

   compile options: '-I/usr/include/python2.7 -c' i686-linux-gnu-gcc: /tmp/6KUBK1XJLW_compiler_check.c i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread /tmp/6KUBK1XJLW_compiler_check.o -o /tmp/6KUBK1XJLW_compiler_check.exe Ready to compile with gcc 5.4.0 . OS: Linux OS version: 4.10.0-38-generic Compiler: i686-linux-gnu-gcc Compiler version: i686-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609 Ready to compile with gcc 5.4.0. extra_args=['-std=c++11'] extra_args=[] building 'libphoebe' extension compiling C++ sources C compiler: c++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC

   compile options: '-I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c' extra options: '-std=c++11' c++: ./phoebe/lib/libphoebe.cpp sh: 1: c++: not found sh: 1: c++: not found error: Command "c++ -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c ./phoebe/lib/libphoebe.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/phoebe/lib/libphoebe.o -std=c++11" failed with exit status 127


   c++: not found
   ```

   I tried it install by

   ```
   sudo apt install c++
   ```

   but it was not successful
3. Third attempt, I tried:

   ```
   pip2 install --user phoebe
   ```

   and I get an error about c++ again

What I do wrong please? Thank you

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/phoebe/__init__.py", line 276, in <module>
    from .dependencies.unitsiau2015 import u,c
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/phoebe/dependencies/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import autofig
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/phoebe/dependencies/autofig/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .call import Plot, Mesh
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/phoebe/dependencies/autofig/call.py", line 2, in <module>
    import astropy.units as u
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    _check_numpy()
  File "/home/betka/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/astropy/__init__.py", line 104, in _check_numpy
    from .utils import minversion
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: I installed something, so `pip2 install --user phoebe suceed` . Now I have a problem that after `python2` and `import phoebe` I get an error `ImportError: No module named utils` . Here is related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064348/no-module-named-utils-error-on-compiling-py-file but I don't understand. I don't know how to find which file is trying to import "utils.py"

Comment: The other way of installing give an error: You cannot import Phoebe from inside its main source tree.

Comment: `from python_utils import *` does not work

Comment: for import error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741254/importerror-no-module-named-utils

Comment: answers in the linked question should be in python2 console?

Answer (score 1):

First, try to install build tool [How to install G++ the C++ compiler on Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-g-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

```
sudo apt install g++
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Then try again.